How to use IPrintDialogServices interface when using IPrintDialogCallback::SelectionChange() to get and change printer settings?
Tell me please how to use IPrintDialogServices interface when using IPrintDialogCallback::SelectionChange to get and change printer settings.
I'm trying to use this construct, but I don't understand how to initialize the IPrintDialogServices:
struct PrintDialogCallback : public IPrintDialogCallback
{
public:
    PrintDialogCallback()
    {}
private:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) noexcept final {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IPrintDialogCallback) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IPrintDialogCallback*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppv = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE HandleMessage(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
                                                       LRESULT *pResult) noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE InitDone() noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SelectionChange() noexcept final {
        IPrintDialogServices *pServices = nullptr;
        // ? how to init pServices ?
        if (pServices) {
            wchar_t printerName[256] = {};
            UINT psize = ARRAYSIZE(printerName);
            HRESULT hr = pServices->GetCurrentPrinterName(printerName, &psize);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                wprintf(L"Selected printer: %s\n", printerName);
            }
            // Other settings
            // DEVMODE *pDevMode = ...;
            // UINT pcbSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
            // hr = pServices->GetCurrentDevMode(pDevMode, &pcbSize);
            // if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pDevMode) {
            //     wprintf(L"Printer paper size: %d\n", pDevMode->dmPaperSize);
            // }
            pServices->Release();
        }
        return S_FALSE;
    }
};


UPDATE
Please tell me how to change the duplex mode for the selected printer?
I'm trying to use this construct but it is not working:
struct PrintDialogCallback : public IPrintDialogCallback, public IObjectWithSite
{
public:
    PrintDialogCallback()
    {}
private:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) noexcept final {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IPrintDialogCallback) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IPrintDialogCallback*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        } else
        if (riid == IID_IObjectWithSite) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IObjectWithSite*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppv = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE HandleMessage(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
                                                       LRESULT *pResult) noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE InitDone() noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SelectionChange() noexcept final {
        if (m_pServices) {
            WCHAR printerName[MAX_PATH];
            UINT nameLen = ARRAYSIZE(printerName);
            if (SUCCEEDED(m_pServices->GetCurrentPrinterName(printerName, &nameLen)) && nameLen > 0) {
                HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
                if (OpenPrinter(printerName, &hPrinter, NULL)) {
                    UINT devModeSize = 0;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(m_pServices->GetCurrentDevMode(nullptr, &devModeSize)) && devModeSize > 0) {
                        HGLOBAL hDevMode = GlobalAlloc(GHND, devModeSize);
                        LPDEVMODE pDevMode = (LPDEVMODE)GlobalLock(hDevMode);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(m_pServices->GetCurrentDevMode(pDevMode, &devModeSize))) {
                            if (pDevMode->dmFields & DM_DUPLEX) {
                                pDevMode->dmDuplex = DMDUP_VERTICAL;
                                LONG res = DocumentProperties(NULL, hPrinter, printerName, pDevMode, pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER);
                            }
                        }
                        GlobalUnlock(hDevMode);
                        GlobalFree(hDevMode);
                    }
                    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
            }
        }
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSite(IUnknown *pSite) noexcept final {
        if (m_pServices) {
            m_pServices->Release();
            m_pServices = nullptr;
        }
        if (m_pSite) {
            m_pSite->Release();
            m_pSite = nullptr;
        }
        if (pSite) {
            m_pSite = pSite;
            m_pSite->AddRef();
            m_pSite->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pServices));
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSite(REFIID riid, void **ppvSite) noexcept final {
        if (m_pSite)
            return m_pSite->QueryInterface(riid, ppvSite);
        *ppvSite = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    IUnknown *m_pSite = nullptr;
    IPrintDialogServices* m_pServices = nullptr;
};


The SelectionChange method is a notification callback. You are not supposed to make changes from there. Regardless, the documentation for InitDone explains when and how to get to an IPrintDialogServices interface.

Per the PRINTDLGEX documentation:

lpCallback
Type: LPUNKNOWN
A pointer to an application-defined callback object.
The object should contain the IPrintDialogCallback class to receive messages for the child dialog box in the lower portion of the General page.
The callback object should also contain the IObjectWithSite class to receive a pointer to the IPrintDialogServices interface. The PrintDlgEx function calls IUnknown::QueryInterface on the callback object for both IID_IPrintDialogCallback and IID_IObjectWithSite to determine which interfaces are supported.
If you do not want to retrieve any of the callback information, set lpCallback to NULL.

And per the IPrintDialogCallback::InitDone() documentation:

If your callback object implements the IObjectWithSite interface, the PrintDlgEx function calls the IObjectWithSite::SetSite method to pass an IPrintDialogServices pointer to the callback object. The PrintDlgEx function calls the IObjectWithSite::SetSite method before calling the InitDone method. This enables your InitDone implementation to use the IPrintDialogServices methods to retrieve information about the currently selected printer.

For example:
struct PrintDialogCallback : public IObjectWithSite, public IPrintDialogCallback
{
private:
    IUnknown* m_Site = nullptr;
    IPrintDialogServices* m_Services = nullptr;

public:
    PrintDialogCallback() = default;
    ~PrintDialogCallback() { SetSite(nullptr); }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) noexcept final {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(static_cast<IPrintDialogCallback*>(this));
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        else if (riid == IID_IObjectWithSite) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IObjectWithSite*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        else if (riid == IID_IPrintDialogCallback) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IPrintDialogCallback*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppv = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() noexcept final {
        return 1;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSite(REFIID riid, void **ppvSite) noexcept final {
        if (m_Site)
            return m_Site->QueryInterface(riid, ppvSite);
        *ppvSite = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSite(IUnknown *pUnkSite) noexcept final {
        if (m_Services) {
            m_Services->Release();
            m_Services = nullptr;
        }
        if (m_Site) {
            m_Site->Release();
            m_Site = nullptr;
        }
        if (pUnkSite) {
            m_Site = pUnkSite;
            m_Site->AddRef();
            m_Site->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_Services));
        }
        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE HandleMessage(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
                                                       LRESULT *pResult) noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE InitDone() noexcept final {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SelectionChange() noexcept final {
        if (m_Services) {
            wchar_t printerName[256] = {};
            UINT psize = ARRAYSIZE(printerName);
            HRESULT hr = m_Services->GetCurrentPrinterName(printerName, &psize);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                wprintf(L"Selected printer: %s\n", printerName);
            }
            // Other settings
            // DEVMODE *pDevMode = ...;
            // UINT pcbSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
            // hr = m_Services->GetCurrentDevMode(pDevMode, &pcbSize);
            // if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pDevMode) {
            //     wprintf(L"Printer paper size: %d\n", pDevMode->dmPaperSize);
            // }
            // ...
        }
        return S_FALSE;
    }
};


Thanks for the answer! Is it really impossible to change the printer settings on the SelectionChange event? For example, I need to set the duplex printing mode when selecting another printer in the dialog. It seems that the documentation does not say that it is forbidden to change the printer settings in response to this event.

@Helg1980 it might help if you edit your question to show what you actually tried that is not working for you.

I have updated the source information and my code.

@Helg1980 this is a Q&A site. Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing comments/answers. I rolled back your edit and changed it to preserve the original question that I had answered. In fact, you probably should delete the edit and post a new question since you are now asking something different than the original question. 1 question per post, please.
